# Redirect not working. $.ajax + Cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Good day.

I have a question I couldn't solve it, I'm using Cakephp and `$.ajax`. The data from `$.ajax` can be passed in to my database. But the problem is I cant redirect to another page when successful.

I had tried the `if($save){ echo something}` and is working, just the `$this->redirect` part.

The Cakephp code as below:

```
public function testingadd() {
        $this->layout=null;

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $phone = $_GET['phone'];

    $this->Newlead->create();


    $this->Newlead->set("name",$name);
    $this->Newlead->set("email",$email);
    $this->Newlead->set("phone",$phone);


    $save = $this->Newlead->save();

    if($save)
    {
        $this->redirect('/Newlead/thankyou');
    }

 }
```

Ajax code as below:

```
$("#btn-submit").click(function ()
    {

    var obj = new Object();
    obj.n = $("#inputName").val();
    obj.e = $("#inputEmail").val();
    obj.c = $("#inputMobile").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Newleads/testingadd.json',
            data: {
                'name' : obj.n,
                'email' :  obj.e,
                'phone' :  obj.c
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout:1000,
            jsonp:'jsonp'
        });
});
```

Is there any more code need to be added to any files in Cakephp such as *routes.php*, *PagesController.php* or any? I'm still new to this. Please help.

Comment: you need to send response back from php to ajax and add a success block in ajax then redirct through ajax

Comment: @RakeshSharma
Response back from php to ajax ? 
For my 'success: function(data, status, xhr)
                {
                    //response = data
                    setTimeout(redirect,100);
                }'

'function redirect()
    {
        //alert('Thank you. We have received your details.');
        window.location = 'url/thankyou.html';
    }'
Not working as well, the error is **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < URL/thankyou.html:1**

Comment: so you have a syntex error try to check console why you added a more function in success block

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384606/cakephp-redirect-method-not-redirecting

Comment: @RakeshSharma you mean console.log ? But I can add the data to my database.

Comment: Always end script after sending a HTTP header (location);

Comment: @RPM Hello RPM, I will keep in mind on the exit() after the HTTP header next time :). 

Thanks alot. 

I learned something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is.

But I've solved it.

```
$.ajax({
[...]
dataType:'jsonp', //have to be Jsonp because I'm using different domain.
error:function(){
  redirect(url);
}
```

It's a bit awkward to do it like this. But, I'm frustrated about the error I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect on the client via JavaScript, depending on your server response:

**Code on Server (controller)**

```
public function testingadd() 
{
    [...]

    if($save)
    {
        return json_encode(array('saveSuccess' => true));
    }
}
```

**Code on Client**

```
$.ajax({
    [...],
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {   

        if(data.saveSuccess === 'true')
        {
            // the redirect
            window.location = '/Newlead/thankyou';
        }

    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert('an error occured');
    }            
});
```

Comment: Hi Simon, I've tried but still not working as well... my page alert me the error... if I change the dataType to Json, I will get this : "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://URL/Newleads/testingadd.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. "

If I put dataType: jsonp, this will shows up "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : testingadd.json:1 "

This have taken me 2 days already, btw thanks for the reply Simon. Appreciated

Comment: At first, make sure, that your url in `$.ajax` is correct. Alter your `url: "/hostname/controller/action"` e.g. `url: "http://localhost/Newleads/testingadd"` and try request again.

Comment: Simon, "XHR finished loading: POST" this came up after my $_GET at Controller page couldn't be use, and I change it to $_POST. Database still normal, can add all the input. Just the redirect part ><. Thank you for your time Simon. Appreciate your solution. :)